# Using the middle name instead of first name for OpenPGP?

Tags: pgp, web-of-trust

I'm just getting started with OpenPGP. I've generated a key, talking to (very few) friends involved with the technology.  But I have a concern: I go by my middle name (with all emails, friends, etc.) but the first name also shows up on IDs.  I used the 'Middle Last' pattern when I created a key.

Will I have any trouble (at signing parties, etc.) if the name with the key doesn't match the name on official ID?  It *will* have the name on it (just as a middle name).

Answer (score 3):

There is no ruling what people have to sign or may not, everybody will decide on his own. You might miss some signatures, but I guess most people will not care about which of the first names is included.

Quite a lot people (at least loosely) follow the rules defined by the [CAcert Practice on Names](http://wiki.cacert.org/PracticeOnNames) document, as CAcert had some well-grounded discussions on names. CAcert's require one, but allow any number of first names to be listed in the certificate.

You will have larger problems when using nicknames, like widely [spread in the Netherlands](https://wiki.cacert.org/PracticeOnNames#Country_variations).